# Compatibility of mounting holes for 775 and 1150 style sockets

Tags: compatibility, heatsink

Will my 775 CPU cooler fit the mounting holes for a 1150 style socket?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the specific cooler you are using, but generally, the answer here is no.  Some coolers will have multiple mounting options via a kit, and hence will fit multiple sockets.  If yours happened to fit without such a kit it would basically be a (happy) coincidence, and there's generally no harm in measuring up to see if things will work out but I would not have high hopes.

Personally, I have seen it be very close, but not fit, and in that case I had the option to buy a separate kit (was actually for a water block) for a reasonable fee.  For cheaper coolers, it probably is not worth it.